# How to download issues from ASF Jira

Tags: data-request, api, data-format

I am currently working with unstructured data, planning to mine the unstructured data present in bug reports.

For this I tried to download the issues from the ASF (Apache Software Foundation) Jira for the project PIG.

The issue tracker allows me to export issues in XML, Excel and Word formats, but I need JSON. The issue tracker throws an 404 forbidden error when I try to export in JSON format.

How can I download the JSON?

1. Must I use the REST API?
2. Does asf jira support a REST API?
3. How to formulate a curl command which uses REST and JQL to accomplish the task?

I tried the following and got an error. What did I miss?

> curl -D -u $username:$password -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://issues.apache.org/jira/issues/search?jql=project=%3DPIzG"

I am trying to download all the issues of the project PIG.

Comment: try jsonp vs json?

Comment: @albert i am pretty much new to JIRA and CURL command. i tried to formulate the curl command by goins through the following Atlassian blog https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftware/blog/2015/06/search-jira-like-a-boss-with-jql  

The command is  

curl -D -u hema:password -X get "http://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/latest/search?jql=project%3DPIG"  

This gives me the following error" PIG is not a valid project"

Comment: i can understand pig is a part of ASF JIRA "https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG/". Even the following command wont return me an json object  

curl -D -u hema:password - H "content-type application/json" -X get "https://issues.apache.org/jira/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20PIG"

Answer (score 3):

you can try this Url https://issues.apache.org/jira/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=projectname

it works with basic authentication.

Answer (score -1):

Atlassian provides documentation for their API's: https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/rest-apis/

There's also this [FAQ in their docs](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/What-is-the-URL-base-for-the-JIRA-APIs-hosted-at-Apache/qaq-p/558860) which gives an apache-specific example URL as

`https://issues.apache.org/jira/rest/api/2/search?jql=assignee=jayunit100`

To answer your specific questions:

> Must I use the REST API?

Probably.  Atlassian also provides a java interface, but I doubt you have access to play with that.

> Does asf jira support a REST API?

It seems to.

> How to formulate a curl command which uses REST and JQL to accomplish the task?

Changing your URL to `"https://issues.apache.org/jira/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=PIG"` should fix it.